# Too many commas?

Tags: support, design, user-interface

Looks like a few extra commas were thrown into this title:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Possible bug?

Comment: It might be my rep, but I don't see that line of text anywhere.

Comment: I'm pretty certain this is a duplicate somewhere, but I can't find it. IIRC the problem back then was indeed an ad-blocker.

Comment: Nope, I don't see it on unanswered SO or Meta questions, even with adblock disabled.

Comment: @Cerbrus: it only appears on questions with 0 answers, and it won't appear on Meta sites at all.

Comment: On reading the title, I thought this was going to be another [diatribe about the Oxford comma](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/199097).

Comment: @DaleWilson: your edit made it sound as if the OP knew perfectly fine that the adblocker was the cause and somehow was blaming Stack Overflow for not handling that situation very well. I don't think that is a fair characterisation and rolled back the edit.

Comment: OK.  My concern was that "Too Many Commaas" was not likely to get people who needed to see this page here.   Any suggestions for a better title?  I think the question is important, but the title is misleading.

Comment: @DaleWilson Adding the filtered text to the question in a text block (instead of just an image) would make it searchable. I'm not sure people using ad blockers who experience this problem would have any idea of the cause, so adding the words "ad blocker" to the question seems unnecessary (and "ad blocker" appears in the accepted answer anyway).

Comment: @DaleWilson And on second thought, simply setting the image's alt text properly should make it searchable.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

It is not that there are too many commas, but that there are too few links. Your browser is hiding the Google+, Twitter and Facebook links:

> [image: the missing links]

If you have an ad-blocker, you probably want to tweak it to not hide those links. Or you have a user script that is broken, or a local office network that tries to hide all things social to keep you focused on work instead.

Try disabling all your extensions and user scripts, or try the same on a different network (say, at home).

In any case, this is **not** a bug on Stack Overflow, but a local problem on *your* side.

Comment: "If you have an ad-blocker, you probably want to tweak it to not hide those links" - or alternatively tweak it to hide the whole line (which mine seems to do by default).

Comment: @l4mpi: the line is only there on questions with 0 answers, and only on sites that have the option enabled. Meta sites don't have it enabled (including Meta.SE), but you should see it on any question with no answers on Stack Overflow or Programmers, etc.

Comment: Ah, I only checked on an already answered question on SO. Seems like it's not hidden for me.

Comment: Indeed, my adblocker was the culprit.

Comment: Answer summary: Works on my machine!

Comment: @Repox Specifically, an adblocker that also blocks social links. (Like, +1, share, etc...)

Comment: I understand that it's not technically a bug of SO, but it is likely to affect many people anyway. Wouldn't it be possible to just add the commas to the links, so people who don't want to see links to social media sites also don't get the commas?

Comment: @shadow: I really don't think it is in Stack Exchange's interest to support third-party tools that alter their UI to this extent, especially when the primary purpose of those tools is to remove advertisements, e.g. part of their livelyhood.

Comment: @shadow: and those tools are configurable too; just tell it to hide the *whole section* if this bothers you. But don't be surprised if SE won't care about those tools. :-)

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't bother me and I'm not trying to "fix" it. The idea was more about new users of SO, who see that the site seems to have "bugs". Anyway, I don't really see why it should bother SE in this case, as these links (presumably?) don't generate any income. But I really don't care about the issue, so never mind my comment...

Comment: @shadow Putting commas inside the links looks super weird, and would distract or confuse the majority of users who don't have the links hidden. Users who are hiding the links can be presumed tech-savvy enough to either (a) recognize what's going on, or (b) fix it themselves.